# Does the phrase "hoping the same" sounds arrogant?

Tags: responses

Suppose, I have written a post regarding achieving some good at my job and earning a few certificates and I got a reply to that: *"Hope your upcoming posts will have more number of certificates."*

I am thinking of replying: "Thank you, I am hoping the same."

Does it sound arrogant? Should I reply "Sure will try"?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it's arrogant.

- If your concern is that it appears that you are too confident of your future success: I would say no, it's a reasonable optimism (especially since you say "hope"). Even a response of "You bet they will!" might not be inappropriate, but seen as cheerful enthusiasm. (An example of what might be *arrogant*, as well as over-aggressive, would be "Of course they will! Why wouldn't they?!")
- If there's a tone problem, it might be that "I am" would normally be contracted to "I'm" in casual speech, so avoiding the contraction sounds a bit formal. There are many shorter constructions that could communicate your intent, like "Thanks, I hope so too!"

Comment: Thanks Andy for such a detailed explanation. Also thanks to Eddie and gotube for the perfect edits. Really appreciated!!!